# How to automatically update information changed in Firestore

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore

I have this code to display username that was stored in Firestore when signing up:

```
   func displayUserName(){
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    
    if let uid = user?.uid{
        
        db.collection("PROFILE").document(uid).getDocument { (snap, err) in
            
            guard let data = snap else {return}
            
            let firstname = data.get("firstName") as! String
            
            self.firstName = firstname
            
        }
       
    }
   
}
```

but, when I change the name in Firestore, I need to relaunch the app so it can update. is it possible to update this name without needing to relaunch the app?

Comment: I don't know about switf, but uou should be able to get so called snapshot that you can listen for changes. getDocument() gets document once

Comment: Thank you, worked flawlessly. Just answered my question. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comment given, I just changed `getDocuments` for `addSnapshotListener`

```
db.collection("PROFILE").document(uid).addSnapshotListener { (documentSnapshot, error) in
            guard let datas = documentSnapshot else {return}
            
            let firstname = datas.get("firstName") as! String
            
            self.firstName = firstname
        }
```